# How to run a script after a Bamboo deployment?

Tags: java, bamboo

I am trying to setup a build and deploy plan using Bamboo (Atlassian).

The build process is working fine, and it's calling the deployment process, but I would like to deploy the built artifact in a specific directory then run it using a java command, typically

`java -jar my_war.war -Djava.awt.headless=true`

From the task type, I can't find something that helps me.

Comment: I found a useful website that gives us a good example: http://smasue.github.io/fat-jar-deployment-bamboo

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Command" task to execute arbitrary commands on the command line.

Then, simply select the Java executable in the "Command" task and provide the other options in the "argument" field below that. Should "Java" not be available in the dropdown, simply add it including the path to it with the button labeled "add new executable".

Specifying the "working subdirectory" may also be necessary depending on where your jar file resides. It defines in which folder your command will be executed and otherwise, the jar file might not be found.